# How to limit number of checkboxes to certain number in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1. This is the code for the checkboxes and I would like to limit the choices to 2.
2. This is going to be used for a pizza application, so the limit number will be different for the different sections in creating a pizza.

```
const LagDinEgen = () => {
    return(
   <div>
        <form name="størrelse">
            <div className="desktop:w-3/4 tablet:w-11/12 w-full mx-auto grid grid-cols-1 tablet:grid-cols-2 desktop:grid-cols-3 rounded-lg overflow-hidden desktop:mt-8 gap-2">
                <div className="col-span-1 tablet:col-span-2 desktop:col-span-3 bg-mainBlue py-10 h-auto text-center text-white flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
            
                    <h1 class="mb-6 pt-6 mx-auto text-center"> VELG STØRRELSE</h1>
                    <div class="mx-auto max-w-sm text-center flex flex-wrap justify-center">

                        <div class="flex items-center mr-4 mb-4">
                            <input id="radio1" type="checkbox" name="radio" class="hidden"/>
                            <label for="radio1" class="flex items-center cursor-pointer px-3">
                            <span class="w-4 h-4 inline-block mr-1 border border-mainGreen rounded-full"></span>
                            SMALL</label> <label>129,-</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex items-center mr-4 mb-4">
                            <input id="radio2" type="checkbox" name="radio" class="hidden" />
                            <label for="radio2" class="flex items-center cursor-pointer px-3">
                            <span class="w-4 h-4 inline-block mr-1 border border-mainGreen rounded-full"></span>
                            MEDIUM</label> <label>159,-</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex items-center mr-4 mb-4">
                            <input id="radio3" type="checkbox" name="radio" class="hidden" />
                            <label for="radio3" class="flex items-center cursor-pointer px-3">
                            <span class="w-4 h-4 inline-block mr-1 border border-mainGreen rounded-full"></span>
                            LARGE</label> <label>189,-</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: pass in the limits using props and accordingly return the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you plan on adding a button, you can utilize the native HTML5 `disabled` property on it and maintain the state of which items are currently selected to determine when it should be disabled(eg. an array of `selectedItems`)

You would pass the `selectedItems.length > 2` to the disabled property, so it would effectively become disabled if your array is larger than 3.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-currying-eb8kt?file=/src/Form.js

Answer (score 0):

You should pass necessary datas to LagDinEgen component as props and then you should use array.map() function inside of JSX. This will be something gonna like that;

```
const LagDinEgen = ({title,options}) => {
    return(
   <div>
        <form name="størrelse">
            <div className="desktop:w-3/4 tablet:w-11/12 w-full mx-auto grid grid-cols-1 tablet:grid-cols-2 desktop:grid-cols-3 rounded-lg overflow-hidden desktop:mt-8 gap-2">
                <div className="col-span-1 tablet:col-span-2 desktop:col-span-3 bg-mainBlue py-10 h-auto text-center text-white flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
                    <h1 class="mb-6 pt-6 mx-auto text-center"> {title} </h1>
                    <div class="mx-auto max-w-sm text-center flex flex-wrap justify-center">
                        {
                            options.map((option,index)=>(
                                <div class="flex items-center mr-4 mb-4">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="radio" class="hidden"/>
                                    <label class="flex items-center cursor-pointer px-3">
                                    <span class="w-4 h-4 inline-block mr-1 border border-mainGreen rounded-full"></span>
                                    {option.name}</label> <label>{option.price},-</label>
                                </div>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```